# .exe file runs perfectly fine on my computer, but doesn't run perfectly on others

Tags: c#

I have a peculiar issue where my .exe that's build from Visual Studio runs and works perfectly on my computer, but when I test it on others, it doesn't work as intended.
The issue in particular is that I have a button that when clicked will disconnect or connect our Always-On VPN connection:

```
        private void _button_ConnectVPN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Button_ConnectVPN.Text == "Always-On VPN: On")
            {
                _disableTaskScehdule();
                _disconnectAlwaysOnVPN();
            }
            else if (Button_ConnectVPN.Text == "Always-On VPN: Off")
            {
                _connectToAlwaysOnVPN();
            }
        }
```

The two methods _connectToAlwaysOnVPN() and _disconnectAlwaysOnVPN() works perfectly fine and disconnects or connects the VPN as intended.

I then have this, that continuously update the background color and text of my button depending on the upstate of Always-On:

```
        Timer aTimer = new Timer();
        aTimer.Interval = 500;
        aTimer.Tick += _updateConnectionStatus;
        aTimer.Start();

    private void _updateConnectionStatus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if(_checkForVPNInterface() == true)
        {
            Button_ConnectVPN.Text = "Always-On VPN: On";
            Button_ConnectVPN.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#ACD1AF");
        }
        else if (_checkForVPNInterface() == false)
        {
            Button_ConnectVPN.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#F47174");
            Button_ConnectVPN.Text = "Always-On VPN: Off";    
        }
    }
```

As mentioned before, when I run this - either via Visual Studio or the .exe file it creates - it runs perfectly and the background color + text is updated accordingly.
On my test machine, the text + background color stays the same. I even tried installing Visual Studio on my test machine and copied the entire solution to it and tried running it through Visual Studio, but it still didn't work as it should.

My initial thought is that I have something that is installed on my computer, which makes it work perfectly - though I don't know what.

Any pointers, comments or anything is much appreciated!

**EDIT:**
Was asked to show the method for _checkForVPNConnection()

```
    private bool _checkForVPNInterface()
    {
        var lastLine = File.ReadLines(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["logPath"]).Last();

        if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
        {

            NetworkInterface[] interfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
 
            foreach (NetworkInterface networkInterfaces in interfaces)
            {
                if (networkInterfaces.Description.Contains("Always-On VPN") && networkInterfaces.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
                {
                    
                    if (lastLine == "Always-On VPN - Disconnected")
                        Logger.WriteLog("Always-On VPN - Connected");
                    
                    return true;
                }
            }
            
        }
        if (lastLine == "Always-On VPN - Connected")
            Logger.WriteLog("Always-On VPN - Disconnected");

        return false;    
    }
```

Comment: Show a code of `_checkForVPNInterface()`

Comment: Have you debugged that method? Have you seen whether your code executes the `if` branch or the `else if` branch?

Comment: check your antiviruses in other computer.

Comment: @Auditive I've edited the post and show the code for _checkForVPNInterface()

Comment: @canton7 Good point - I haven't tried that on my test machine

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm using System.Windows.Forms.Timer

Comment: @MadsBrockmannJuhl You just need to sit down and debug your application on the machine where it doesn't work. Does `_checkForVPNInterface` return the correct thing (I'm betting it doesn't)? If not, why not: step into it and see which line is not doing what you expect. Then figure out *why* it's doing that. Then fix it.

Comment: Those double calls to `_checkForVPNInterface()` will run the VPN check twice. If the state of the VPN changes from one call to another, neither branch will execute. `if(_checkForVPNInterface()){ ...} else {...}` is enough

Comment: Add logging to your code and write the network state for all interfaces to a log file. Perhaps the interface isn't what you expected. Perhaps there are transitions that are missed by your code. **DON'T** use the log file to detect transitions though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @canton7 pointed out in his comment, I ran the debugging on the test machine and found that the Networkinterface both have "Always-On VPN" (which I need) and "Always-On VPN User Tunnel" - which is always up, even if the connection is disconnected.

Because I had:

```
networkInterfaces.Description.Contains("Always-On VPN") && networkInterfaces.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up
```

It worked as it was (poorly) designed ;)

I have now changed the:

```
networkInterfaces.Description.Contains("Always-On VPN")
```

to:

```
networkInterfaces.Description.Equals("Always-On VPN")
```

And it worked like it should